# Is there a cross-platform CMake command to install a project?

Tags: cmake

CMake comes with a cross-platform way to compile projects which is `cmake --build .`. Is there a similar command to install a project? I'm looking for something that translates to `make install` on Unix but also works on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmake --build . --target install